# Select all faces within an area delimited by sharp edges

Tags: selection-tools

I've got a model that has sharp edges around islands.  I want to keep the sharp edges, and be able to select only the faces inside the island borders.  Any ideas?

I'm able to select a single row around the island.

[image]

Then one more row.

[image]

Any more than that and the selection selects things outside of the island.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can easily select one row of faces around the island then the hard part of the issue is solved.

Just select that single face loop and hide it with <kbd>H</kbd>, then select one of the remaining faces at the center of the island and select all linked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Unhide the hidden loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, and it should include it in selection automatically

[image]