# Is there any way to select a smoothing group?

Tags: edges, selection-tools, select

I have a mesh with designated sharp edges here and there, broken into few "smoothed" areas. I wonder if there is any way to select polygons within a "smoothed" area, that is surrounded by sharp edges? I can't find anything in selection menu or in documentation and selecting these polygons manually every time becomes tedious and takes a lot of time. In other words, is there anything similar to "selection by smoothing groups"?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/select-all-faces-within-an-area-delimited-by-sharp-edges

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found a solution. *Select - Select Linked* and choose *Sharp* in a pop-up submenu.